# want to get data from mysql as string

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
DB::table('follow_ups')
->select(
  'created_at as start',
   DB::raw('count(*) as title')
)->groupBy('created_at')->get()->toArray();
```

above query is returning title as integer, i want this value as string

Comment: Your query appears to be returning a count that is labeled 'title'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COUNT(*) is an aggregation function that will count distinct titles in a group. If you want to get all titles you need a different aggregation function that can (somehow) return all members of the group. There is one option that is generally available (i.e. even in older MySQL versions):

[GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
DB::table('follow_ups')
->select(
  'created_at as start',
   DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(title) as title')
)->groupBy('created_at')->get()->toArray();
```

This will return all group members concatenated via the delimiter you specify (default is `,` if you don't specify one)

Newer MySQL versions also have [JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)

```
DB::table('follow_ups')
->select(
  'created_at as start',
   DB::raw('JSON_ARRAYAGG(title) as title')
)->groupBy('created_at')->get()->toArray();
```

This will return the result as a json array which you can then decode using `json_decode($row['title'],true)`

The advantage of the 2nd method is that it's easier to get individual values of the group in the cases where the group members contain the delimiter e.g. there's some title that contains a comma and would therefore make GROUP_CONCAT a bit useless.

Note: Both these functions are MySQL/MariaDB specific as far as I know so if you plan to make your database portable you might want to avoid them and look for alternatives that are ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: sorry i didn't mention, i want to get no. of count of each date that is in created_at column in "title" and that too as a string.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your expected result. Can you  update your question to share some sample data and what result you expect to get?